# Crop and Resize Image to Specific Dimensions

Tags: c#, resize-image

I need some help cropping and resizing images using CSharp.net. My goal here is to take an image and reduce it to 50px by 50px. The following code I found here will do that, however it's scaling the image as well. Ideally I want to scale the image down to as close to 50px by 50px as possible and then remove the parts of the image that are outside 50px by 50px.

```
public Image ResizeImage(Image img, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b))
    {
        g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    }

    return (Image)b;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can find answer in this question: [Best resize and or crop logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626355/best-resize-and-or-crop-logic)

Comment: It did, the link in this post resolved my issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626355/best-resize-and-or-crop-logic/1649349#1649349